# nltk .lhs() issues with comparing strings

Tags: python, nltk

When assigning `string = i.lhs()` its value, then later comparing with
`print (var == 'P')` returns false when `var` is `'P'`.

```
 for i in grammar.productions():
    var = i.lhs()
    P = "P"
    if (not i.is_nonlexical()):
        print var
        print (var == P)
```

it returns false on anything. I don't understand why it returns false on everything. Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare lhs()-objects with strings, but you can get the object's string representation with `.lhs().__str__()`, and compare that with another string, like so:

```
for i in grammar.productions() :
   var = i.lhs()
   P = "P"
   if (not i.is_nonlexical()) :
       print var
       print (var.__str__() == P)
```

Also, you can use `is_lexical()` instead of asking if it's **not nonlexical**